# How to generate IDs based on column values

Tags: sql-server

I will provide examples and code where I can. Assume everything except [CycleStart] and [CycleEnd] datatypes are Varchar, I'm not too fussed about this at this stage.

**Table A** consists of the following RAW sample data:

```
+-------+---------+----------------+------------+------------+
| JobID | JobName | CycleDesc      | CycleStart | CycleEnd   | 
+-------+---------+----------------+------------+------------+
| 10003 | Run1    | January 2019   | 31/12/2018 | 31/12/2018 |
| 10005 | Run2    | December 2018  | 31/12/2017 | 31/11/2018 |    
| 10006 | Run3    | March 2019     | 31/12/2018 | 31/02/2019 |    
| 10007 | Run4    | September 2019 | 31/12/2018 | 31/09/2019 |  
| 10008 | Run5    | November 2019  | 31/12/2018 | 31/10/2019 |     
+-------+---------+----------------+------------+------------+
```

**Table B** consists of the following sample data and the code used to generate this data is below:

```
+-------+---------+---------+
| JobID | PeriodID | Entity |
+-------+---------+---------+
| 10003 | 202101   | XYZ1   |
| 10003 | 202112   | XYZ2   |   
| 10007 | 202008   | XYZ3   |   
| 10007 | 202003   | XYZ4   |   
| 10008 | 201904   | XYZ5   |   
+-------+----------+--------+
```

```
Declare  @Counter3 INT

SELECT @Counter3=1

WHILE @Counter3 <= 1000
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableB]

SELECT
FLOOR(RAND()*(33979-1+1))+1 [JobID]
,CAST(ROUND(((2021 - 2019 -1) * RAND() + 2020), 0) AS VARCHAR) + RIGHT('0'+CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*(12-1+1))+1 AS VARCHAR),2) [PeriodID]
,FLOOR(RAND()*(23396-1+1))+1 [Entity]
```

The issue lies within Table B column [PeriodID]. This column represents an ID generated from [CycleStart] in Table A e.g. 31/12/2018 = 201812 (YYYYMM).

What I want to show in **Table B** is a Period ID for each Job ID but show **EACH** month + 30 years ahead of the [CycleStart] date. Example table of what I am looking to achieve:

```
+-------+---------+---------+
| JobID | PeriodID | Entity |
+-------+---------+---------+
| 10006 | 201812   | XYZ1   |
| 10006 | 201901   | XYZ2   |   
| 10006 | 201902   | XYZ3   |   
| 10006 | 201903   | XYZ4   |   
| 10006 | 201904   | XYZ5   |  
| 10006 | 201905   | XYZ5   |
| 10006 | 201906   | XYZ5   |
| 10006 | 201907   | XYZ5   |
| ...   | +30yrs   | ...    |
| 10006 | 204812   | XYZ5   |
+-------+----------+--------+
```

How can I achieve this? Currently I am just randomly generating IDs which is not related to the [CycleStart] date and therefore just skewing my data but this is the only way I can think of doing it.

Comment: @nbk im using microsoft SQL server 2012 if thats what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to create a calendar table / date dimension.  You can use this table to solve this issue, and reuse it for other problems later.  (Search online for some examples on how to build one).

If you have this table then you only need to join this table and that's it.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO TableB ( JobID , PeriodID)
SELECT DISTINCT A.JobID , D.TheYear * 100 + D.TheMonth 
FROM tableA A
JOIN myDateTable D
    ON D.TheDate BETWEEN CONVERT(date , A.CycleStart ,  103) AND DATEADD(YEAR,30, CONVERT(date , A.CycleStart ,  103));
```